# How can I connect my domain to my Minecraft server without port-forwarding?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, domain, minecraft

I've been working on ways to host my Minecraft server free of charge, on my own computer. Since I'm at my university and I can't access the network settings I can't use port-forwarding, so I turned to Ngrok, which is great, but it's extremely annoying that it generates a new domain each time it restarts. Now I want to be able to use a Freenom domain to connect to my server.

How can I route this domain's traffic to a port on my computer without port-forwarding?

Ideally I'd be able to set up a tunnel in a similar way to how Ngrok does, between my new permanent domain and my Minecraft server, without spending money.

Answer (score 0):

This very likely won't be possible. On top of that, if you find some way of doing this, you'll be using someone's bandwidth. They will eventually notice and figure out a way to stop it.

You can get *very* cheap "VPS" servers these days (couple $ a month) that could be setup to port forward to your home machine with a persistent SSH connection, for instance. That might be enough for you.

Comment: Once you are into vps $ territory, just use a VPN (with a static IP) instead and call it a day.

Comment: Or just pay ngrok for a fixed number